# equivalent of entry.objects.filter(foreignkey__attribut='x') with .get() on django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-orm

I want to recover just one line filtered with foreignkey's attribut.

I use this format:

```
tmp = Entry.objects.filter(foreignkey__attribut='x')
```

but it shows me this error

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'attribut'
```

I use `Entry.objects.get(foreignkey__attribut='x')` but it didn't work

Comment: please format your code -- highlight code, press {} button at top of edit box.  How didn't it work? Did you get a traceback? or bad result?

Comment: You need to make sure that `attribut` is a field in your `foreignkey` model. Is that the case?

Comment: There's no way that either of those calls would produce that error; at best you would get "Cannot resolve keyword "foreignkey" into field". The error is coming from *somewhere else* in your code, which is why you need to post the actual code and the full traceback.

Comment: this is the code :

Answer (score 0):

If i've understood what you want, You wanna just do an `Entry.objects.get(foreignkey='x').attribut`